# .remove() not working in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working with jQuery and it doesn't want to remove an input element I have. The rest of the script goes through fine, it just seems to ignore a .remove() command I give it.

So basically I have a few div (replicated in foreach statements), and in it I have a documentTitle class where inside is the printed value of a document title. When clicked, it loses the div and puts the value of the div inside an input field, this is the particular script for that portion:

```
function divClicked() {
    var divHtml = $(this).html();
    var editableText = $("<input class='form-control controlTitle' name='title'>");
    editableText.val(divHtml);
    $(this).closest(".documentTitleHover").addClass('editing');
    $(this).siblings( ".fa-check" ).removeClass('hidden');
    $(this).replaceWith(editableText);
    editableText.focus();
}
```

Now my issue arises with what happens when a little checkmark in the top righthand portion is clicked, a lot of things happen, and they work flawlessly (including the ajax portion), but the one and only thing that refuses to work is the .remove();

Here is that particular script:

```
$("span.fa.fa-check").click(function () {
  var checkMarkSpan = $(this);
  var parentDocumentDiv = checkMarkSpan.closest("div.document");

    var html = $(this).siblings( "input[name='title']" ).val();
    var viewableText = $("<div class='documentTitle'>");
    $(this).closest(".documentTitleHover").removeClass('editing');
    $(this).siblings( ".fa-check" ).addClass('hidden');
    viewableText.html(html);
    $(this).replaceWith(viewableText);
    $(this).siblings(".controlTitle").remove();
    // setup the click event for this new div
    viewableText.click(divClicked);

  // now do the Ajax. Notice how the inputs are searched below the div, not everywhere ($)
  $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url: '/carrier/claims/files/updateFile',
            data: {
                'attachmentID': parentDocumentDiv.find('input[name=attachmentID]').val(),
                'title': parentDocumentDiv.find('input[name=title]').val(),
               '_token': parentDocumentDiv.find('input[name=_token]').val(),
            },
            success: function(data) {
                    $('.errorTitle').addClass('hidden');
                    $('.errorContent').addClass('hidden');

                    if ((data.errors)) {
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            $('#createOrigin').modal('show');
                            toastr.error('Check your inputs!', 'Error Alert', {timeOut: 5000});
                        }, 500);

                        if (data.errors.title) {
                            $('.errorTitle').removeClass('hidden');
                            $('.errorTitle').text(data.errors.title);
                        }
                        if (data.errors.content) {
                            $('.errorContent').removeClass('hidden');
                            $('.errorContent').text(data.errors.content);
                        }
                    } else {
                        toastr.success('Changed Title Successfully To '+data.claim.title, 'Success Alert', {timeOut: 5000});
                       $('#existing_consignee_details').html(
'<strong>'+data.customer_name+'</strong><br>'+data.billing_address_1 +' '+data.billing_address_2 +'<br>'+data.billing_city +', '+data.billing_state + ' '+data.billing_zipcode+'<br><br><a href="/customers/i/'+data.id+'" target="_blank"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">View Customer Details</button></a>' );

                    }
                },

                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                  if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                      alert('Internal error: ' + jqXHR.responseText);
                  } else {
                      alert('Unexpected error.');
                  }
                }
            });
});
```

Near the top, in the second block of script, you see the .remove near the bottom.

As for the HTML, before the div is actually clicked, this is what an individual "document" looks like:

```
<div class="documentTitleHover">
                                <div class="documentTitle">Document 14</div>
                                    <span class="fa fa-edit"></span>
                                    <span class="fa fa-check hidden"></span>
                            </div>
```

And this is what it looks like after the div is clicked:

```
<div class="documentTitleHover editing">
                                <input class="form-control controlTitle" name="title">
                                    <span class="fa fa-edit"></span>
                                    <span class="fa fa-check"></span>
                            </div>
```

And this is what it looks like after the checkmark is clicked:

```
<div class="documentTitleHover">
                                <input class="form-control controlTitle" name="title">
                                    <span class="fa fa-edit"></span>
                                    <div class="documentTitle">Document 15</div>
                            </div>
```

As you can see from my script, when the checkmark is clicked, the input is supposed to be removed, but it stays there on top of the newly created div.

Comment: Why do you cache `$(this)` in `var checkMarkSpan = $(this);` and still keep using it on all the subsequent lines of code? It would help the clarity and readability of the code alot if you didn't keep using `$(this)` that much after doing several additional jQuery selections.

Comment: Unfortunately, that just looks like a really stupid mistake of mine. Thanks for catching it. Unfortunately nothing has changed on the output though I have fixed the script to remove the $(this)'s and replace them with checkMarkSpan.

Comment: That is probably because you're replacing that element (`$(this).replaceWith....`) before the `$(this).siblings(".controlTitle").remove()` statement.

Comment: @Titus - if I remove the replaceWith, no div appears afterward. The input is gone but I still need the div to reappear.

Comment: Reverse those statements' order, first remove the `input` then replace the `span`

Comment: @Titus - That worked perfectly. Thank you. Do you want to go ahead and post your answer and I'll accept it? Thanks again!

Comment: I've posted an answer and tired to explain what is causing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're replacing the `this` element with another one and because of that, `$(this).siblings(".controlTitle")` won't return any elements (`this` not longer has a sibling with class `controlTitle`).

To fix that you can either remove the `input` before you replace the `span`:

```
$(this).siblings(".controlTitle").remove();
$(this).replaceWith(viewableText);
```

Or change the way you find the `input`

```
$(this).replaceWith(viewableText);
viewableText.siblings(".controlTitle").remove();
```